# Understanding HTTP sessions in JSF as session attributres are going null unexpectedly while working actively on the application

Tags: java, jsf-2, session-variables, tomcat8

We're having a very large web application, entirely built with JSF (2.0)/PrimeFaces (8.0). Running on remote Tomcat 8 server (Linux OS)
We are facing a very serious issue due to which our server logs are filling up enormously.

The issue is : A user, after login, while working actively on the application [Inactivity timeout (30 mins, default) not reached] like filling up a form, the session attributes are going null unexpectedly and on an Ajax call, filters intercept the request and check for username which is stored in session
created at login, on getting username from session, it is giving `null` value and redirecting the user to login page.

And when user logs in again, same issue. And in 3rd attempt it is working absolutely fine. (This is just an example, sometimes started working as expected in 2nd attempt)

This is happening randomly, not always.

We have checked entire code for `session.invalidate()` but no issues, it is written where it should be like on Primefaces IdleMonitor timeout (10mins) and on logout. Also checked for `.getSession(true)` but no issues, it is written where it should be. Not anywhere in between.

We are trying to get it solved for last 3 days but no success...

Below is the approach which we are using in our application for session management.

**Login Bean**

```
@ManagedBean(name="login")
@ViewScoped

public class LoginBean implements Serializable
{
    private String username;
    private String password;
    String baseURL;
    public constructor()
    {
        HttpSession ss = (HttpSession) FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getSession(false);
        if(ss!=null)
        {
             ss.invalidate();
        }

        baseURL = //some https://url where the application is hosted.
    }

    public void login()
    {
        //login DAO to check for login success
        if(loginSuccess)
        {
            HttpSession ss = (HttpSession) FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getSession(false);
            if(ss!=null)
            {
                 ss.invalidate();
            }
            
            ss = (HttpSession) FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getSession(true);
            ss.setAttribute("username", username);

            PrimeFaces.current().executeScript("window.location.replace('"+baseURL+"homePage.xhtml');"); // just to avoid navigation to login page using browser's back button
        }
    }
}
```

After login, getting values from session on `homePage.xhtml`'s associated bean, this way:

```
@ManagedBean(name="home")
@ViewScoped

public class HomeBean implements Serializable
{
    private String username;
    
    public constructor()
    {
        HttpSession ss = (HttpSession) FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getSession(false);
        username = (String) ss.getAttribute("username");
    }
}
```

This way, we're accessing username from session in our entire application

**Filter :**

```
public class MyFilter implements Filter {

    String userName="";
    
    @Override
    public void destroy() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response,
            FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {

        HttpServletRequest req=(HttpServletRequest) request;
        HttpServletResponse res=(HttpServletResponse) response;

        HttpSession session = req.getSession(false);
        userName=(String) req.getSession().getAttribute("username");
        
        String requestUrl = req.getRequestURI();
        String loginURL = req.getContextPath() + "/login.xhtml";
        String expiryURL = req.getContextPath() + "/expired.xhtml";
        
        
        if (!requestUrl.contains(ResourceHandler.RESOURCE_IDENTIFIER))
        {
            if(!requestUrl.contains("/login.xhtml") && !requestUrl.contains("/expired.xhtml"))
            {
                if(session == null) {
                    if ("partial/ajax".equals(req.getHeader("Faces-Request"))) {
                        res.setContentType("text/xml");
                        res.getWriter()
                            .append("<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>")
                            .printf("<partial-response><redirect url=\"%s\"></redirect></partial-response>", expiryURL);
                    } else {
                        res.sendRedirect(expiryURL);
                    }
                }
                else
                {
            
                    if(userName==null  || userName.equals("") )
                    {
                        session.invalidate();

                        if ("partial/ajax".equals(req.getHeader("Faces-Request"))) {
                            res.setContentType("text/xml");
                            res.getWriter()
                                .append("<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>")
                                .printf("<partial-response><redirect url=\"%s\"></redirect></partial-response>", expiryURL);
                        } else {
                            res.sendRedirect(expiryURL);
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        chain.doFilter(request, response);
                    }
                }
            }
            else
            {
                if(requestUrl.contains("/expired.xhtml"))
                {
                    if(session!=null)
                    {
                        session.invalidate();
                    }
                }

                chain.doFilter(request, response);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            chain.doFilter(request, response);
        }

    }
    @Override
    public void init(FilterConfig arg0) throws ServletException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

}
```

**Primefaces Idle Monitor :**

```
<h:form>
   <p:idleMonitor timeout="600000">
       <p:ajax event="active" listener="#{idleBean.expire()}" />
   </p:idleMonitor>
</h:form>
```

This is included in our UI template using <ui:include>

**Idle Monitor Bean**

```
@ManagedBean(name="idleBean")
@ViewScoped

public void expire() throws IOException
{
    HttpSession ss = (HttpSession) FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getSession(false);
    if(ss!=null)
    {
        ss.invalidate();
    }
    
    FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().redirect(baseURL+"/expired.xhtml");

    return;
}
```

One more thing I wanted to add, as the application and the code is a bit old (~5years), it is having a random navigation or page switching mechanism like somewhere `return(pagename.xhtml)` and somewhere `ExternalContext#redirect(pagename.xhtml)`. I'm not sure but suspecting this also for session issues.

The issue mentioned above is not coming always but randomly and is very annoying. Like it is happening anytime, while navigating to other page or while filling up a form and during ajax call or button clicks within 3-4 minutes of logging in.

Please help me understanding whether this approach is fine or not. If there are any flaws which are causing session attributes going `null`. Please suggest for solving this issue or improving this approach.

Comment: There's a conceptual misunderstanding. JSF **does not** manage sessions. The servlet container and the server(s) do (and actually also the client). You would still have had exactly the same problem when using a different servlet based framework than JSF. You need to reframe your question to focus on that instead. In the servlet end, the most common mistake causing the described symptoms is that the app is deployed on a cluster/cloud with session replication/failover and that the WAR isn't properly preconfigured for that.

Comment: But I’m not understanding the statement ‘when using a different servlet based framework than JSF’, the app is not using any other framework than JSF. And the deployment is also not on a cluster, but yes the application and the database are on different servers, one server for app and other is for DB. Can this also be problematic?

Comment: It means your question is about whatever container you're using, not JSF, so should be written and re-tagged accordingly. This seems perfectly clear to me.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the corrections. Can we discuss on the issue and any possible solution... if you've any suggestions or something..

Comment: When you use a different framework than JSF then you would still have observed **exactly the same** problem of sessions not being maintained. Why is that? This is because JSF is **not** responsible for managing sessions. You need to take a step back and focus the problem at server/client level, not at JSF level. Your current question has all information about JSF but very little information about server/client config. All that information about JSF is completely irrelevant to the real problem. You need to rewrite your question. Now re-read the first comment. Do you understand it now?

Comment: Got your point… let me have a thorough check with the server guys, will come up with the findings if something looks weird… Thank you so much for the suggestions!

Comment: The issue got solved now. The problem is due to the proxy server. We reconfigured it and is solved now. Thanks for the suggestions!